# attribute values are displaying in frontend only from store view

Tags: attributes, store-view, default-values

i needed to convert an dropdown attribute to multi select attribute.

so i followed this link : http://swarminglabs.com/how-to-change-a-product-dropdown-attribute-to-a-multi-select/

Than i got this problem & solution here :

[Attributes did't selected in backend after changed from dropdown to multi-select](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101129/attributes-didt-selected-in-backend-after-changed-from-dropdown-to-multi-select/101189?noredirect=1#comment136453_101189)

after this , i can able to get the attributes in frontend only when we select our store view of site.

but i want this to work for when we select "Default values" also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did the previous answer from Shivani not solve this?

Maybe you can check the values in the catalog_product_entity_varchar table. They should have the store_id 0 to be considered default

**===UPDATE===**

with the following query you can find the entries with the non default values for your attribute (given your attribute id is 1244, which i have from you other question):

```
select entity_id,store_id from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = 1244 and store_id != 0
```

if you find some (or many) we would have to check in the next step, if they have default values or not

**===UPDATE===**

I wrote a query that will assign the value for the attribute 1244 to the default store if there isn't one defined already.

Although I'm pretty sure that this works, you really should make a db backup before executing update queries on your database

```
UPDATE IGNORE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET store_id =0 WHERE attribute_id =1244
```

**===UPDATE===**

the update statement did actually not work but updated it and its easier now

Comment: yes, it worked for store views. i want for "Default values". i checked the table, it mentioned "0" as store id

Comment: i checked in 1st page, store id is 0 for all rows, is i need to look for particular attribute ?

Comment: just updated, if you get a result, we can take the next step

Comment: i got this result : http://prntscr.com/a1if47

Comment: just to check if the first entity has a default, would you execute this query pls: select entity_id,store_id from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = 1244 and entity_id=219

Comment: please check here : http://prntscr.com/a1ii9g

Comment: ok, here is the problem. If there was a default value, there would be another entry with the store_id 0, but there is not. I think I can work out an update query that sets every store_id to 0 when there is no default defined. So you only have values for your store with the id 1 and thats why they are only showing there

Comment: sure, please give me that query

Comment: it's in the answer. If you know how, pls make a db backup ;)

Comment: i can award this bounty only after  10 hours, i will award it...... but believe me you are awesome ,  saved my day.

Comment: no problem :) glad I could help you